# AngularJS ng-model for multiple inputs inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I basically have a directive with 21 inputs in it. I want to set ng-modelbased on an attribute passed when calling the directive. Now if I do `{{myAttr}}` inside my directive it outputs the attribute I've set, but if I include it like `ng-model="{{myAttr}}"` things break.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('program', function () {
return {
  templateUrl: 'app/program/program.html',
  restrict: 'EA',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.dayModel = 'program.' + attrs.day + 'First';
  }
};
});
```

Comment: {{myAttr}} is only for replacing html text, by the value of myAttr at runtime. I think ng-form="myAttr" should work, if ng-form takes input like that, which I'm not entirely sure at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You use `{{variablename}}` only in pure html-text, so that angularjs can replace it by the value of your variable at runtime:

http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/hb7lu/

But you would never write `ng-form="{{myAttr}}"` in an html-tag, instead you have to write `ng-form="myAttr"` The `{{}}` serves as a way for angularjs to distinguish between plain text and variable/code. But in html-tags there is no plain text, instead everything is interpreted as variable/code.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too, but doing it this way fills the input the variable as well and decided to try something else.

Comment: can you fill your html and angular-code into a new http://jsfiddle.net/ so that I can take a look at everything ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jcxa3mhv/1/
Ofc it won't work but for visualizing what I have, I think it should be enough.

Comment: Oh god,  I just realized I've put ng-form in stead of ng-model in the title. Dumb me... Sorry about this.

Comment: No, I mean the question here. :D The actual code is right.